# Ajax inside a While Loop Crashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want a while loop that iterates if the amount paid is greater than zero. But running the code crashes the browser.

```
var amount = Number($('#payment1').val());
while (amount > 0){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  baseurl + "collection/getSingleAmort",
        data: {'contractid':contractID},
        success: function(result){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(data);
            var amortizationAmount = Number(data['amortization'][i].amortization_amount);
            amount = amount -amortizationAmount;
        },
        error: function (errorThrown){
            //toastr.error('Error!', 'Operation Done');
            //console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: don't forget that ajax is async. Rather than a naive loop you need to wait for the ajax call to return and give you the new value before you move to the next call. This way is going to make a right mess, or, like you say, end up crashing things with a massive loop and dozens of ajax calls trying to run.

Comment: Just implement a callback function which forces to wait for the Ajax response.....

Comment: Guys thanks for all your help. I added "async: false," to my ajax and everything worked out fine. Much respect!

Comment: @Azis yuk. That'll produce a horrible user experience (it locks the browser while requests are in progress. If you make a lot of requests in a loop, the user might think the browser has crashed since they can't click on anything). Also, some browsers have already deprecated synchronous ajax requests, so you can reasonably expect your code to stop working again at some time in future. Far better to do as myself and yash suggested.

Comment: @Azis Further, see See https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#synchronous-flag for details.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but adding the async: false did the trick. There are no errors and the request returns fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `async:false`

```
var amount = Number($('#payment1').val());
while (amount > 0){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  baseurl + "collection/getSingleAmort",
        data: {'contractid':contractID},
        async:false,
        success: function(result){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(data);
            var amortizationAmount = Number(data['amortization'][i].amortization_amount);
            amount = amount -amortizationAmount;
        },
        error: function (errorThrown){
            //toastr.error('Error!', 'Operation Done');
            //console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it is indeed a bad idea, but for quick fix this will work until you can find a workaround. i would strongly recommend to not use this with large data equests.

Answer (score 1):

```
function xyz(amount){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  baseurl + "collection/getSingleAmort",
        data: {'contractid':contractID},
        success: function(result){
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            console.log(data);
            var amortizationAmount = Number(data['amortization'][i].amortization_amount);
            amount = amount -amortizationAmount;

            if(amount>0)
                xyz(amount);
        },
        error: function (errorThrown){
            //toastr.error('Error!', 'Operation Done');
            //console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

var amount = Number($('#payment1').val());
xyz(amount);
```

Try something like this. Instead of looping recursion is used.

Comment: This is also a good answer. But adding async: false to my code fixed it. It didnt crash. It didnt took too long for the request to be made.